# Insignificant improvement after Grid Search

Tags: python, machine-learning, grid-search

I am running some algorithms for classification purposes on a dataset regarding bus schedules. Specifically, I run some random forests and a part of my source code is the following:

```
# Instantiate random forest
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
random_forest = RandomForestClassifier()

# K-Fold Cross Validation (for grid search)
inner_cross_validator = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=k_fold, shuffle=True)


from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

# Define parameters for grid search
number_of_trees = {'n_estimators': [100, 300, 500]}
max_features_per_tree = {'max_features': [0.2, 0.5, 0.8]}
min_samples_split_per_node = {'min_samples_split': [0.2, 0.5, 0.8]}
parameters = {**number_of_trees, **max_features_per_tree, **min_samples_split_per_node}

# Execute grid search and retrieve the best classifier
best_random_forest = GridSearchCV(estimator=random_forest, param_grid=parameters, scoring='average_precision', cv=inner_cross_validator, n_jobs=3)
best_random_forest.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

However, after Grid Search the precision and the recall are not improved almost at all.

In general, in my experience with other datasets in the past, I have not noticed an improvement of more than 5% or rarely 10% at the scores of the various metrics after grid search in comparison with the default values of a library like SkLearn.

Can I do something (after the stage of feature engineering) to improve significantly more the performance of my classification model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 5%-10% increase from hyperparameter tuning is a significant increase. You should not expect a greater increase than that from GridSearch.

Other than feature engineering (which has a very large scope for increase in performance) you can try:

1. Randomised Search: To search for randomly selected hyperparameter values within defined ranges. This should 
   http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html
2. Using a different algorithm: You are currently using RandomForest. This is a very effective method to reduce the variance of your predictions and slightly increase the performance. However, other methods like Gradient Boosting should give you better performance.
3. Ensembling of different Algorithms: This is a very broad topic and covers many different ways to combine models for increased performance. https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/06/comprehensive-guide-for-ensemble-models/

Comment: Thanks for your answer(upvote). Essentially, I wanted someone to corroborate my initial suspicion. In this sense, I eventually feel that after the stage of feature engineering you cannot do much more than simply running the algorithms (and perhaps getting to an improvement of 5% with Grid Search). If you need bigger improvement then you should collect more data, clean them more appropriately, do better feature engineering etc.

Comment: Yes, but do not discount the benefits you can get from different algorithms and ensembling. I do agree that feature engineering is extremely important, particularly in tree based algorithms where even different encoding technique can change performance.

Comment: P.S. @amanbirs "However, other methods like Gradient Boosting should give you better performance". Finally, boosters gave me way worse performance. Have a look here (https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/38535/xgboost-performs-significantly-worse-than-random-forest) if you want for more information.

Comment: Answering there.